# How can I change the value of nodeURL in each element of FingerTableEntry

Tags: java

FingerTableEntry:

```
public class FingerTableEntry {
    
    public String nodeURL;
    
    public FingerTableEntry () {
        this.nodeURL = "";
    }
    
    public void setURL (String nodeURl) {
        this.nodeURL = new String(nodeURL);
    }
    
}
```

Node:

```
public class Node {

    private FingerTableEntry FingerTable[];
    
    public Node() {
        FingerTable = new FingerTableEntry[31];
        for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
            FingerTable[i].setURL("A");
        }       
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Node node = new Node(); 
    }

}
```

The end result I'm hoping for is that FingerTable[i].nodeURl is set to "A" instead I get the error: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Updated Your Code The Null Pointer Exception Occures Because You are not Calling The Constructor Of The FingerTableEntry Class Which Does Not Initialize The Variable And The Exception.

(Except Changing The Value Of This Url In Seperate Function Change It In The Constructor Itself Which Will Initialize The Variable And Also This Is A Great Practise).

```
public class FingerTableEntry {
    
    public String nodeURL;
    
    public FingerTableEntry (String url) {
        this.nodeURL = url;
    }    
}
```

```
public class Node {

    private FingerTableEntry FingerTable[];
    
    public Node() {
        FingerTable = new FingerTableEntry[31];
        for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
            
            FingerTable[i]=new FingerTableEntry("A");
        
        } 
        
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Node node = new Node(); 
    }

}
```